# When will positive sum of random variables converge to the sum of positive ones?

Tags: convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of identically distributed continuous random variables $x_1, \dots x_N$, with $x_i \in [0,C]$,  and a constant $0\leq a\leq C$.

We know by Jensen's inequality that

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N (a - x_i)\bigg)^+ \leq \sum_{i=1}^N (a - x_i)^+,$$

where $(y)^+=\max\{0,y\}$.

Under what conditions, will $\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N a - x_i\bigg)^+$ converge to $\sum_{i=1}^N (a - x_i)^+$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Hint: consider the cases $a\lt \mu,$ $a=\mu,$ and $a\gt \mu$ separately where $\mu$ is the common expectation of the variables.

Comment: what mode of convergence are you interested in?

Comment: Convergence in probability.